# Are questions about why something didn't happen on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

[Why was there never a dub for Skip Beat?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/why-was-there-never-a-dub-for-skip-beat) was originally closed but reopened when it was changed to 'Why didn't it happen' rather than 'When will it happen'

Another question appeared recently https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/has-tokyo-ghoul-been-dubbed-in-english asking "Why has Tokyo Ghoul root A not been dubbed in English?" which was closed under unannounced future events.

Is it on-topic or off-topic to ask why something hasn't been done?

Comment: personally i think they have the same problems as unannounced events

Comment: Sometimes there might be some known story behind why something didn't happen that answers can recount (e.g. if I asked "Why wasn't Kodomo no Jikan released in the US?", there's a well-documented story behind it). But largely, I agree that they have the same problems as unannounced future events: there's no way to know unless you have inside info.

Comment: Not sure if on topic here, but at least related; Unannounced future events seem to be a problem on its own. Questions about future events seem to be closed regardless whether they are actually announced or not. While I agree they are bad questions and would be solved by a simple google query in most cases, it seems we don't even bother to check first (the same goes for image ID requests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we can allow questions asking **why** as long as:

1. The OP includes in the question the latest news or announcement about the event, **and**
2. It must be at least one year since the date of the announcement if the announcement doesn't specify a date of the event, **or** at least one month since the date of the event as stated in the announcement, **and**
3. The OP have to show some evidences that the event didn't happen (basically, *do your homework*).

Answer (score 2):

As no one has formed their opinion in an answer, I propose that these should be closed as off topic as they are consistently unanswerable due to no information being available.

Even if you were a head of a company - there are other companies too that license series.

I think plot-related / in-story questions should stay though as these can be attributed to plot holes, other characters influences etc.